# multiple dynamic javascript upload buttons

Tags: javascript, css

I need help dynamically creating upload buttons.

I've created a function to create the `input` and `label` elements for the buttons and formatted the label with CSS so that a label is clicked to open the upload file dialog window while the main `input` element is hidden.

When I fun the function, it successfully generates a upload button with the first button working fine, but because the label's `htmlfor` tag is looking for a unique `id`, i I can't seem to dynamically create more upload buttons.

I've tried replacing the `htmlFor` id with `label.htmlFor = label.previousElementSibling;` but that doesn't work.

Here is what i have:

```
function addButton() {
var upload = document.createElement("input");

var col11 = document.createElement("td")

var upload = document.createElement("input");
    upload.type = "file";
    upload.id = "receipt";
    upload.className = "uploadClass";

    var label = document.createElement("label")
    label.innerHTML = `<i class='material-icons center'>file_upload</i>`;
    label.htmlFor = label.previousElementSibling;
    label.className = "custom-file-upload";

    col11.appendChild(upload)
    col11.appendChild(label)
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
input[type="file"]{
display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 6px;
cursor: pointer; 
}
```

It seems that the issue is creating dynamic `htmlFor` tags for each button label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I'm using `Date`'s `getTime` method to generate an `id` for file input. Feel free to use whatever solution you like when generating a unique ID.

```js
function generateInputId() {
   return new Date().getTime();
}

function addButton(inputId) {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    const td = document.createElement("td")
    const label = document.createElement("label")

    input.type = "file";
    input.id = inputId;
    input.className = "uploadClass";
    
    label.innerHTML = `<i class='material-icons center'>file_upload</i>`;
    label.htmlFor = inputId;
    label.className = "custom-file-upload";

    td.appendChild(input)
    td.appendChild(label)
    return td;    
}

const row = document.getElementById("row")
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

Array(3).fill(0).forEach(() => fragment.appendChild(addButton(generateInputId())));

row.appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
input[type="file"]{
display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 6px;
cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr id="row"></tr>
 </tbody>

</table>
```